# Make a position:absolute div scroll normally within another scrollable div

Tags: css, scroll, positioning, css-position

I have a fixed height scrollable `<div id="overlay">` positioned over all the page elements using `position:fixed`. In the div I have elements higher than the fixed height, so the scrollbar appears. I also have a tooltip that I want to stay with a paragraph even if it is scrolled.

That's what I want to happen here, but unfortunately neither of my solutions work properly:

1. I add `position:absolute` to the tooltip and `position:relative` to `#overlay`(the tooltip's parent): http://jsfiddle.net/4qTke/

   The tooltip scrolls as expected but it is not visible outside of `#overlay`.
2. I only add `position:absolute` to the tooltip: http://jsfiddle.net/Yp6Wf/

   The tooltip is visible outside of the parent `#overlay` but doesn't move when the div is scrolled.

I want the tooltip to always be visible *AND* for it to move when scrolled.

Comment: really good rewriting, thank you !

Comment: You are welcome. Happy to have helped. Is there just one tooltip; and where does it need to appear i.e. beneath the paragraph or to the side of it and inside or outside of the container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is not possible using just CSS and HTML.

The main problem you have is that you have set `overflow: scroll` on the container your `#tooltip` is relative to. Because this overflow property is stopping any content from appearing outside of its edges when you position `#tooltip` "outside" of the `div` it will be hidden and only visible when scrolled to.

The reason it was visible in your second scenario is because without setting `position:relative` your `#tooltip` was relative to the page and not the container. Which meant it was not affected by the `overflow:scroll` property of the container.

Comment: You're right, i didn't think about it that way.. I guess i'll have to put the paragraph that has a tooltip at the top of the scrollable area so that it doesn't overflow too often.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div id="overlay">

    <div class="elemRel">

        <div class="elemAbs">

            <!-- Your Code -->

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
#overlay { position:fixed; }
.elemRel { position:relative; }
.elemAbs { position:absolute; }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that's what i did in my 1st point, and that's not what i want :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an alternative for you? See [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/kg8r4/).

Comment: That would make it for a regular usage, but not in my case, i really need the tooltip to stay under the paragraph, and to follow it when i scroll. I guess @tw16 is right, and there's no way to do this, at least not without using some JavaScript.